# Как объявить список в GNU Prolog?

Tags: prolog, gnu-prolog

Решаю логическую задачу типа задачи Энштейна. В материале, посвящённом решению подобных задач, приведён код на SWI-Prolog. Пытаюсь перевести этот код в GNU Prolog, но проблемы идут уже с первой строчки. Конкретно у меня не получается объявить список с опр. именем.

В SWI это выглядит так:

```
List = [_,_,_,_,_].
```

Когда я пытаюсь выполнить этот код в GNU, выводится след. ошибки:

```
warning: singleton variables [List] for (=)/2
native code procedure (=)/2 cannot be redefined (ignored)
```

Изучение документации пока меня ни к чему не привело. Может, кто-нибудь подскажет, как это правильно делается в данной реализации пролога?

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете применить предикат `length(List, Length )` т.е.

`?- length( List, 5 )`.

Переменная `List` будет связана со списком, содержащим пять *несвязанных переменных*, в качестве элементов списка.